# When looking at subdirectories, skip one directory

Tags: directory-structure, output, variable-substitution

I have a directory `/u01/oracle/folders` with these subfolders:

```
[root@ricusesasctl01vm tax_receipts]# ls -ltr
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 Argentina
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 Brazil
drwxr-xr-x 3 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 completed
drwxr-xr-x 3 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 duplicate
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 EAO
drwxr-xr-x 3 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 errored
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 Japan
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 Korea
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 SAO
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 SPPO
drwxr-xr-x 3 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 temp
drwxr-xr-x 4 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 template
drwxr-xr-x 3 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 template2
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 Mar  1  2021 WHQ
drwxr-xr-x 5 OICDev1 oic 4096 May 10  2021 Canada
drwxr-xr-x 3 OICDev1 oic 4096 Jun  8  2021 canada
```

In a shell script,

```
SourceDirectory="/u01/oracle/folders"
TargetDirectory=/u01/oracle/folders"
```

For the value of `$SourceDirectory`, I want to list all the subfolders except SAO.

Using this command in loop

```
#100 Loop through each directory (e.g. brazil, canada, uk)
#
for EachDir in "$SourceDirectory"*;
do
 strFiles=""
 echo "Current Directory is $EachDir"
```

I tried :

```
SourceDirectory=$(find /u01/oracle/folders -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name SAO \))
```

It skips the directory SAO, but the output is one long string.  How do I split this string into directories?

Example:

```
[root@ricusesasctl01vm tax_receipts]# SourceDirectory=$(find /u01/oracle/folders -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name SAO \))
[root@ricusesasctl01vm tax_receipts]# echo $SourceDirectory
/u01/oracle/folders /u01/oracle/folders/duplicate /u01/oracle/folders/Brazil /u01/oracle/folders/completed /u01/oracle/folders/template2 /u01/oracle/folders/Canada /u01/oracle/folders/SPPO /u01/oracle/folders/template /u01/oracle/folders/WHQ /u01/oracle/folders/EAO /u01/oracle/folders/errored /u01/oracle/folders/Korea /u01/oracle/folders/Japan /u01/oracle/folders/Argentina /u01/oracle/folders/temp /u01/oracle/folders/canada
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /u01/oracle/folders -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name SAO \) | while read SourceDirectory
do
  echo "$SourceDirectory"
  ls "$SourceDirectory"
done
```

Comment: How do you pass the above as value to variable? I'm trying to pass the resultant directories as paths to loop thru...  in the shell script i want the values of the above find  to be fed as values to SourceDirectory variable

Comment: That's exactly what it does. Did you try it?

Comment: There was a syntax error in the find, the braces had to be escaped (protected from shell interpretation).

Comment: Note that this also gives the top-level search path to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily skip the `SAO` directory in your simple shell loop:

```bsh
SourceDirectory=/u01/oracle/folders

for dirpath in "$SourceDirectory"/*/; do
    case $dirpath in
        */SAO/) continue ;;
    esac

    # Process "$dirpath" in whatever way is needed.
done
```

With `bash`, you could replace the `case ... esac` with

```bsh
[[ $dirpath == */SAO/ ]] && continue
```

In either case, this code uses a filename globbing pattern test to check whether the string in `$dirpath` matches `*/SAO/`, which it would do if it ends with the literal string `/SAO/`.

Another way to do this with `bash` is through using an extended globbing pattern in the loop:

```bsh
shopt -s extglob

SourceDirectory=/u01/oracle/folders

for dirpath in "$SourceDirectory"/!(SAO)/; do
    # Process "$dirpath" in whatever way is needed.
done
```

The pattern used for the loop would match all directories in `$SourceDirectory`, apart from any directory called `SAO`. To be able to use extended globbing patterns in the `bash` shell, they need to be enabled via `shopt -s extglob`.

I would not use `find` here as we know exactly what single directory we want to skip.

If you feel you *really need* to do this with `find`, I would suggest doing it like so:

```bsh
SourceDirectory=/u01/oracle/folders

find "$SourceDirectory" ! -path "$SourceDirectory" -prune \
    -type d ! -name SOA -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        # Process "$dirpath" in whatever way is needed.
    done' sh {} +
```

Or, with GNU `find`:

```bsh
SourceDirectory=/u01/oracle/folders

find "$SourceDirectory" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -type d ! -name SOA -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        # Process "$dirpath" in whatever way is needed.
    done' sh {} +
```

This uses `find` as a generator of strings to iterate over.  These strings are pathnames of all the directories under `$SourceDirectory`, except for the `SOA` directory.

The processing that you want to do would be done from the in-line script provided to `sh -c` on the command line.